# How can I find a DataTemplate via code?

Tags: wpf, resources, datatemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Knowing a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is defined somewhere in the resource tree (i.e. it could be defined at the app level, in a `style`, in the window's resources or somewhere in the hierarchy of controls on that window), programmatically, how can you determine which `HierarchicalDataTemplate` will be applied for a particular data type relative to a specific control?

For instance, in the following example, given that we have an object of type Foo, how can we get the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for it--which happens to be defined at the window level here--relative to MainTreeView?

```
<Window ... >

    <Window.Resources>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Foo}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate> 

    </Window.Resources>

    <TreeView x:Name="MainTreeView" />

</Window>
```

I've tried the following but it returns null:

```
var hdt = (HierarchicalDataTemplate)MainTreeView.FindResource(typeof(Foo));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it.  `DataTemplate` objects don't use DataType for their default key like `Style` objects do. Instead, they use a `DataTemplateKey` object which you get as follows...

```
var dataTemplateKey = new DataTemplateKey(dataItem.GetType());
var hdt = (HierarchicalDataTemplate)MainTreeView.TryFindResource(dataTemplateKey);
```

That worked! :)